# C++ Is there a way to loop through a vector and return a message only once it's been searched through entirely

Tags: c++, vector

This is just for one of the exercises in my book, where it asks me to search through a vector for a specific name and return a score from another corresponding vector once the name has been found. If the name isn't found, it'll return the message "Name not found!"

```
int main()
{
    vector<string>name;
    vector<int>score;
    string n = "0";
    int s = 0;
    while (cin >> n >> s && n != "NoName") {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i)
            if (n == name[i]) {
                cout << "Error! Name is already in database!" << '\n';
                break;
            }
        name.push_back(n);
        score.push_back(s);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i)
        cout << "(" << name[i] << " " << score[i] << ")" << '\n';
    cout << "Type in a name to find the score" << '\n';
    string search = "0";
    cin >> search;
    for (int i = (name.size() - 1); i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
        if (search == name[i])
            cout << "Score is " << score[i] << '\n';
        else
            cout << "Name not found!" << '\n';
    }
}
```

The above is my code. The only problem I'm having is that it'll loop through the vector and return "Name not found!" multiple times because it searches each individual position. I only want it to return the message once the whole vector has been searched. I've tried googling it, and I've found something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "some string");

if (it != vec.end())
{
   std::cout << "Found '" << *it << "' in the vector." << std::endl;
}
```

which, unfortunately, I don't quite understand.

Comment: `if ... else` statements always do either the `if` or `else` part. `if(...) return; else return;` will always `return`, for example.

Comment: Hmm, so if I did else return; for my second portion of my code, it would only iterate "Name not found!" only once?

Comment: Well, technically, but that wasn't my point. And the program would close. My point is that when you're writing `if else` structures, keep in mind that either one thing gets executed, or the other. If that isn't how it should work, it shouldn't be put there.

Comment: Oh yes, I knew that if else would only result in one result occurring, I just overlooked that it would loop through the vector and give the result each time for a position. That was my fault. However, I haven't gotten too far into the book and I wasn't really taught any option to try to produce what I needed to for this problem, so I relied on the if else statement. Thank you for the clarification though.

Comment: are you searcing in reverse order on purpose?

Comment: Yes, I was, but I was doing it to test something. It worked so I just left it there. I had it in normal order at first.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "some string");
```

This searches for the string `"some string"` in the range `[vec.begin(), vec.end()[` and returns an iterator to the element in the range if it is found. If it is not found, the end of the range (`vec.end()`) is returned.

So `if (it != vec.end())` is saying `if (the string was found)`.

---

Regarding your original code and the unwanted prints, there are several ways of fixing that. One way would be:

```
int i;
for (i = (name.size() - 1); i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    if (search == name[i]) break; // exit the loop as soon as the element is found
}

if (i >= 0) {
    cout << "Score is " << score[i] << '\n';
} else {
    cout << "Name not found!" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Ah, alright! That makes sense. So I can just use const_iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "insert name here") and then if (it != vec.end()) cout << "Score is: ". 

I have another hopefully quick question. I've searched up some other results and it brings up non constant iterators and shows me this code: 

void print(const std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
 for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
 {
  std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
 }
}

What does *iter do in this situation?

Comment: `*iter` would give you the string that you're currently looking at in the range. Note that if you're using a C++11-compliant compiler you don't have to type all those awful type names. You can just say `auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "some string");`.

Comment: And if you don't intend to use the iterator for anything other than to compare it with `vec.end()` you can just say `if (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "some string") != vec.end())`

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = std::find(name.begin(), name.end(), name_to_search);`

Please refer to function template [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/). It searches range [name.begin(), name.end()) and compare every element with "name_to_search". It returns an  iterator to the first element that is equal to "name_to_search".

If no elements match, the function returns `name.end()`.

P.S. You can also go through the range like this:

`int i = 0;
    for (; i < name.size(); i++) {
        if (search == name[i]){
            cout << "Score is " << score[i] << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == name.size()){
      cout << "Name not found!" << '\n';
    }`

Comment: Oh, that's really helpful! I didn't realize you could just declare int i = 0 outside and then immediately put a semicolon inside the for loop. I have a question though, because there isn't really anything in the for loop that would stop the loop after it's found the name, wouldn't i always eventually equal name.size() anyways and then activate the if statement?

Comment: the `break;` is used to stop the loop after the name is found.

Comment: Would i essentially just retain whatever number it was before break stopped it?